# how to send two parameters with livewire emit in javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, emit

I have a function in livewire component like this :

```
public function deleteAccount($id,$approve){
// my code ...
}
```

and I want to emit this function from javascript. I tried :

```
<script>

 window.livewire.emit('deleteAccount', data => {123, true});

</script>
```

But it does not worked. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Try as `('deleteAccount', ['id' => 123, 'approve' => true])`

Answer (score 3):

##### form livewire to  js

```
$this->emit('showDate',$this->date_from, $this->date_to);

 Livewire.on('showDate', function (from, to)    });
```

##### from js to livewire

```
Livewire.emit('showDate', 123, true)

function showDate($date_from , $date_to){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<script>
 window.livewire.emit('deleteAccount', [123, true]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Livewire.emit('deleteAccount', 123, true)
```